# How could we handle massive AWS SNS Mobile push notifications (with dynamodb and lambdas)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns

We save a huge list of followers in DynamoDB (more than 10K) and we need to send a push notification to each follower each time an item is created.
And i am worried that (NodeJS) lambdas only have a limit of 15 minutes, not enough time to query the list from DynamoDB and send all SNS push notifications one by one.

I think i might be tackling the issue without the correct tools, any suggestions?

Comment: `each time an item is created`.. where is the item created?

Comment: It's created on DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to query DDB nor send SNS notifications for each subscriber.

You should have 1 SNS topic and when you add a subscriber to your DDB list, you subscribe them to the SNS topic.

Now sending a message to all 10K subscribers is just sending a single message to the SNS topic.

**Edit**
Since you've commented that the item you're sending the notification about is created in DDB.  Then what you want to do is enable DDB Streams and have a lambda process the stream and send the single message to SNS; which will then go out to the 10K subscribers.